# Scroll to top button is not hidden using css display:none;

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the following script for scroll to top function,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
```

**html**

```
    <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

**css**

```
    .scrollup{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    left:100px;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url('{{ 'icon_top.png' | asset_url }}') no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .scrollup {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i'm using this script the display:none; in my css (under @media) is not in use. i need it to hide the button in mobile devices.

Using the bottom script (with different css) is working fine, but i want to use the above for the fadeIn fadeOut use.

What i'm missing?

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if(window.scrollY > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').css('bottom', -8);
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').css('bottom', -100);
    }
});
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: var d  = $(window).width();
if(d < 767)
{
    $(".scrollup").attr("hidden","hidden");
} check this is working or not...

Comment: earlier you are using @media so .. css way , this one is a javascript way.. add on onload means when your document ready

Comment: found how do that from css, added visibility: hidden;

Comment: ya that you can do , i have used here html5 attribute hidden.. you can use visibility:hidden , display:none